# Why is in statistical thermodynamics $β=\frac{∂\ln\left(Ω\right)}{∂U}=\frac{1}{k_{B}T}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

Why is in statistical thermodynamics $β=\frac{∂\ln\left(Ω\right)}{∂U}=\frac{1}{k_{B}T}$? $β$ appears later during the derivation of the Boltzmann canonical partition function.

$Ω$ is the number of accessible microstates for a canonical ensemble (I think, that it is important here, that it is not a microcanonical ensemble).
$U$ is the internal energy of the system.
$k_{B}$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the absolute temperature.

Is this relationship related to the fact that the temperature of a system depends only on its translational kinetic energy and not on its potential energy or other forms of kinetic energy?

This equation appeared in the lecture without much explanation, and I want to understand the role of this equation: Is it a definition? An axiom? A theorem (i.e. something that can be proven)? Is there a unique answer or does the answer depend on the context?

I'm particularly interested in knowing if the validity of this equation can be proved or if it is a postulate.

In my own textbook it is said about this equation: "Strictly speaking, we can only conclude here that $β$ must be a monotonically decreasing function of the temperature. [After introducing] the statistical interpretation of the entropy [it will be] clear that $β$ [must be] proportional to the reciprocal temperature [in order to be] phenomenological consistent with the statistical definition of entropy."

So, I understand that only because of the assumption made by Boltzmann that $S=k_{B}\ln\left(Ω\right)$ we can conclude that $β=\frac{∂\ln\left(Ω\right)}{∂U}=\frac{1}{k_{B}T}$, because $\left(\frac{∂S}{∂U}\right)_{V,N}=\frac{1}{T}$. In conclusion, the validity of the relationship $β=\frac{∂\ln\left(Ω\right)}{∂U}=\frac{1}{k_{B}T}$ cannot be demonstrated and is only a consequence of the Boltzmann definition of entropy. Is this correct?

Comment: It is a definition.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker A definition of what?

Comment: I don't understand (and also I don't understand the edit) it is a definition of the (inverse absolute) temperature.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Okay, so $$T=k_B\frac{\partial\ln\Omega}{\partial U}$$is the definition of $T$. I think that your comment answers the question.

Comment: @Filippo Well, it is not the most general definition, but an instant of it (where $S=\ln \Omega$). Of course there are certain motivations for this definition etc. (e.g. that this coincides with our 'every day' understanding of temperature); but this should be covered in the lecture. In any case, it is discussed in every book on statistical mechanics.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Actually, the identification of thermodynamic quantities with the Statistical Mechanics formulae is often not very clear both in lectures and textbooks. This question is far from trivial.

Comment: @GiorgioP I've never said that the question is trivial. But it was/ is unclear what exactly the point of the question is. If it is to understand the relationship between thermodynamics and statistical mechanics (with the example of temperature, e.g.), it should be edited accordingly.

Comment: Yes, now I recall the formula$$\frac{1}{T}(E,V,N):=\frac{\partial S}{\partial E}(E,V,N)$$from my thermodynamics lecture. To be precise, I think that we are considering the special case $$S(E,V,N)=k_B\ln\Omega(E,V,N).$$

Comment: To the OP: You would probably get bonus points for saying what textbook you are reading (if you are lucky, someone who read that book can give a more specific answer). Also, feel free to remove my edit, it was just an attempt to reopen the question.

Comment: @Filippo I found your edit very useful.

Comment: There is additional information related to my question here: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Statistical_Mechanics/Boltzmann_Average/Proof_that_%CE%B2_%3D_1%2F%2FkT
and here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_beta

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to identify which thermodynamic properties correspond to which statistical properties.

1. Start with the entropy of classical thermodynamics:
   $$\frac{dS}{k} = \frac{dU}{kT}-\frac{PdV}{kT} + \frac{\mu dN}{kT}
   \Rightarrow 
   \boxed{\frac{S}{k} = \frac{U}{kT}-\frac{PV}{kT} + \frac{\mu N}{kT}}
   $$
2. Now to statistics: postulate the number of microstates $\Omega(E,V,N)$ to have the *homogeneity* property $$\log\Omega(\lambda E,\lambda V,\lambda N) = \lambda\log\Omega(E,V,N)$$
3. Apply Euler's theorem
   $$\boxed{\log\Omega 
   = \frac{\partial\log\Omega}{\partial E}E
   + \frac{\partial\log\Omega}{\partial V}V
   + \frac{\partial\log\Omega}{\partial N}N
   }
   $$
4. Assuming $E$ and $U$ to be the same thing, postulate the equalities by direct comparison between the boxed results:
   $$ \log\Omega = \frac{S}{k}$$
   $$ \frac{\partial\log\Omega}{\partial E} = \frac{1}{kT}$$
   $$ \frac{\partial\log\Omega}{\partial V} = -\frac{P}{kT}$$
   $$ \frac{\partial\log\Omega}{\partial N} = \frac{\mu}{kT}$$
5. Accept these as exact equalities until contradicted  by experiment

Why should $\log\Omega$ be homogeneous, as postulated in step #2? Naive lattice calculations and calculations with non interacting particles (classical or quantum) show this to be the case.

Comment: $\log \Omega$ is not homogeneous generally, but we need it to be in order to make the connection with thermodynamics. The general argument that it *is* homogeneous is something like: "make a second identical copy of the system and place it right next to the first one. If there is no interaction energy then the new system has twice the energy, twice the volume, etc. The number of states of the new system is the product of the number of states of each individual system, so the log of the number of states of  the new system is twice the original."

Comment: Too many postulates and not convincing arguments for the homogeneity of $\log \Omega$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that we can define a function $Ω\left(U,V\right)=e^{\frac{S\left(U,V\right)}{k_{B}}}$ and we must postulate, that this function is equivalent to the number of microstates in a microcanonical ensemble, defined as follows: $Ω\left(U,V\right)=\frac{1}{h_{0}^{F}}\int_{Γ}^{ }δ_{D}\left[H\left(q_{1},q_{2},...,q_{F},p_{1},p_{2},...,p_{F},V\right)-U\right]\prod_{i=1}^{F}dq_{i}dp_{i}$, where $F$ is the number of degrees of freedom of the system, $h_{0}^{F}$ is the volume of a phase space cell and $H$ is the Hamilton function, depending on the generalized positions and impulses.

Comment: I understand why $\ln\left(Ω\right)$ is homogeneous. If I duplicate a system $A$ with an $Ω_{A}$ number of microstates, then the number of microstates of the duplicated system is not $2\cdotΩ_{A}$, but $Ω_{A}\cdotΩ_{A}$. This can also be seen from the entropy. Let $S_{A}$ be the entropy of the system. The entropy of the double system is then $2\cdot S_{A}$. If we use the relation $Ω_{A}=e^{\frac{S_{A}}{k_{B}}}$, then $e^{\frac{2\cdot S_{A}}{k_{B}}}=e^{\frac{S_{A}}{k_{B}}}\cdot e^{\frac{S_{A}}{k_{B}}}=Ω_{A}\cdotΩ_{A}$. So $\ln\left(Ω_{A}\cdotΩ_{A}\right)=2\ln\left(Ω_{A}\right)$.

Comment: So, we have two homogeneous functions, that depends on the internal energy of the system, on the volume of the system and on the number of particles:
$\ln\left(Ω\left(U,V,N\right)\right)$ and $S\left(U,V,N\right)$.
Because they are both homogeneous, we postulate that they are proportional to each other. Is there any mathematical proof, that if we have two homogeneous functions that depends on the same variables and have the same homogeneity degree, then this functions must be proportional to each other? Then we would no longer have to postulate anything.

Comment: @Schtroumpf Fucntions with the same degree of homogeneity are not necessarily proportional to each other, for example $x+y$ and $(x^2+y^2)/(x+y)$. So the situation is this: we have a statistical construction, $\log \Omega$ that behaves in all testable ways the same as entropy. Gibbs developed the basic theory of statistical mechanics in Ch 4 of his book, but still wrote another 11 chapters  to convince himself that the predictions of the theory make sense. In a sense the validity of stat mech is a postulate, but for all practical purposes it is an unassailable fact.